# Modeling a circuit with arrows

Tags: haskell, arrows

I have:

```
class Arrow circ ⇒ Circuit circ where
    wire    :: circ Bool Bool
    notGate :: circ Bool Bool
    orGate  :: circ (Bool , Bool ) Bool

    wire = id
    notGate = arr not
    orGate = arr $ uncurry (||)
```

I want to implement:

```
-- A and B
andGate :: Circuit circ ⇒ circ (Bool , Bool ) Bool
-- not (A and B)
nandGate :: Circuit circ ⇒ circ (Bool , Bool ) Bool
-- A xor B
xorGate :: Circuit circ ⇒ circ (Bool , Bool ) Bool
```

I don't want to use something so simple as (arr and) but combine the function that already have. I fail to grasp how compose arrows as you do with functions.

Thank you.

Comment: You do know how to implement `&&` in terms of `||` and `not`?

Comment: @Alec: [`wire = id`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html#v:id) is actually fine.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ah yes. I wish we had only one version of `(.)` and `id`. :(

Comment: @Alec I don't. I myself use almost only the polymorphic versions, but it's probably good that the prelude keeps it more simple for beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you look at [`Control.Arrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html), in particular [`(***)`, `(&&&)`, and `(>>>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-). [This tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows) is also really good.

- `(***)` allows you to take two arrows and put them side by side into an arrow that has both inputs and outputs (as tuples):

  ```
  (***) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b, b') (c, c')
  ```
- `(&&&)` lets you again combine two arrows and get a tuple of their output, but this time both of the arrows will consume the *same* input:

  ```
  (&&&) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')
  ```
- `(>>>)` lets you sequence (compose) two arrows. This is very similar to function composition. In fact, `(>>>)` is just the generalized `(.)` from `Control.Category` with its arguments flipped.

  ```
  (>>>) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a c d -> a b d
  ```

  (Actually, the constraint only needs to be `Category`, but that is beside the point here.)

Then, we can use some common logical equivalences to get `andGate`, `nandGate` and `xorGate`:

```
-- Use (x NAND y) === ((NOT x) OR (NOT y))
nandGate :: Circuit circ => circ (Bool, Bool) Bool
nandGate = (notGate *** notGate) >>> orGate

-- Use (x NAND y) === (NOT (x NAND y))
andGate :: Circuit circ => circ (Bool, Bool) Bool
andGate = nandGate >>> notGate

-- Use (x XOR y) === ((x OR y) AND (x NAND y))
xorGate :: Circuit circ => circ (Bool, Bool) Bool
xorGate = (orGate &&& nandGate) >>> andGate
```

#### Aside on `-XArrows`

There is a really neat syntax extension that let you write `Arrow`s using a special `do`-like notation. This is somewhat more readable than the cryptic `Control.Arrow` operators, especially when you have a bunch of arrows interacting.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

 nandGate :: Circuit circ => circ (Bool , Bool ) Bool
 nandGate = proc (x,y) -> do
              x' <- notGate -< x
              y' <- notGate -< y
              orGate -< (x',y')

 andGate :: Circuit circ => circ (Bool, Bool) Bool
 andGate = proc (x,y) -> do
              z <- nandGate -< (x,y)
              notGate -< z

 xorGate :: Circuit circ => circ (Bool, Bool) Bool
 xorGate = proc (x,y) -> do
              z <- orGate -< (x,y)
              w <- nandGate -< (x,y)
              andGate -< (z,w)
```

Comment: Great answer, I understand now how this work, and the do notation is even better. AND is correct? Should be NOT (a OR b), right?

Comment: No, I think it is right. Might want to check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) again.

Comment: now if you want to do something more complicated like:

(A and B) or (C and D)

With the awesome do notation is a breeze:

parallel = proc ((a, b), (c,d)) -> do
                   e <- andGate -< (a,b)
                   f <- andGate -< (c,d)
                   orGate -< (f,f)

But how you do it with the other notation?

Comment: @MartinR. You'll have to sprinkle the expression with 'let's